# Не нашел решение на ошибку AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

Во время написания другого кода, столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу заставить работать массив в функции. Решил написать более простой код, что бы понять в чем проблема. Сам решить ее я не смог.

```
class I():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def run(self):
        print(self.x + self.y)

def run():
    # b = I(1, 2)
    # b.run()

    arr = []
    create_array(arr)

    draw_array(arr)

def create_array(array):
    array.append(I(1, 2))
    array.append(I(2, 3))
    array.append(I(3, 4))

def draw_array(array):
    for i in array:
        I.run(array)

run()
```

в ответе должно выводиться 
3
5
7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 2 ошибки, обе в одной команде. ;-)

В конце программы, в определении функции `draw_array()` вместо

```
I.run(array)
```

используйте

```
i.run()          # строчная буква i; в скобках нет параметра
```

---

Переменной цикла `for` является **строчная** буква `i`, а у метода `.run()` класса `I` **нет параметров** (кроме «скрытого» параметра `self`, представляющего ссылку на конкретный объект класса `I`).

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @ali, не стоит. -:)